# Proof limit of ratio of sequence .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that as $n\to\infty$
$$\frac{1}{x_n} \to \frac{1}{x}$$

where we are also given $x_n \to x$, and $x_n,x\neq0$

Attempt: Suppose $x_n \to x$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural $N$ such that $$\left|\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x}\right| < \epsilon.$$

Now, $$\left|\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x} \right| = 
\frac{|x - x_n|}{|x_n||x|}$$
Now assume $|x_n| \geq C$ since $x_n$ is convergent it is bounded.

Can anyone please help? I get confused on the epsilon part. Thank you.

Comment: You can just use that $x \mapsto \frac 1 x$ is a continous function for $x>0$.

Comment: And also for $x<0.$

Comment: And for a proof of that, look for instance at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;\{x_n\}\;$ is convergent to $\;x\neq 0\;$ and $\;x_n\neq 0\;$,  there exists $\;0<C\in\Bbb R\;$ s.t. $\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;|x_n|>C\;$.

Also, for any $\;\epsilon >0\;$ there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t.

$$\;n>N\implies |x_n-x|< \epsilon\cdot C\cdot|x|\;(\text{this is a constant times}\;\epsilon!\,)$$

Thus we have, for $\;n>N\;$, that

$$\left|\frac1{x_n}-\frac1x\right|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{|x_n||x|}<\frac{\epsilon\cdot C\cdot|x|}{C|x|}=\epsilon$$

which proves that

$$\frac1{x_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1x$$