# Limit of reciprocal function is the reciprocal of its limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta, supremum-and-infimum

Let $g$ be continuous on the interval $[a, b]$, and a $< c < b$ with $g_{(c)}<0$

Prove, using the epsilon and delta characterisation of a limit, that $\lim\limits_{x \to {c}}\frac{1}{g{(x)}} = \frac{1}{g{(c)}}$
Hence deduce that $\frac{1}{g}$ is continuous at $c$

I know that there exists $g {(x}$) smaller than $\frac{g {(c)}}{2} < 0$ and I can use this information somehow but other than that I am not sure how to approach this question. Is there any special laws I need to follow?

Comment: Start by the very definition: for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that... and then use that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: yeah i know that much.. its continuing from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The limit of reciprocal is the reciprocal of the limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939852/the-limit-of-reciprocal-is-the-reciprocal-of-the-limit)

Comment: Not really a duplicate because the latter was asking for a proof explanation.

Comment: A smarter (and more usual) proof of the continuity of $\frac1g$ at $c$ is to consider it as a composition of two continuous functions: $y\mapsto\frac1y$ and $g$ (if necessary, prove the continuity of the former, but this way the notation are less heavy).

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, and for all $c\in [a,b]$, there exists a $\delta(\epsilon,c)>0$ such that

$$|g(x)-g(c)|<\left(\frac{g^2(c)}{2}\right)\epsilon \tag 1$$

whenever, $|x-c|<\delta(\epsilon,c)$.

So, if we take $\epsilon=\frac12|g(c)|$, then we see that $\frac32g(c)<g(x)<\frac12g(c)$, since $g(c)<0$, whenever $|x-c|<\delta(g(c),c)$.

Therefore, we can write for all $\epsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{g(c)}\right|&=\frac{|g(x)-g(c)|}{|g(x)|\,|g(c)|}\\\\
&\le\frac{|g(x)-g(c)|}{\frac12|g(c)|\,|g(c)|}\\\\ 
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-c|<\min\left(\delta(\epsilon,c),\delta(g(c),c)\right)$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, let us start by what we have to show: for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that 
\begin{equation}
 \Bigg| \frac{1}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{g(c)} \Bigg| = \Bigg| \frac{g(c) -g(x)}{g(x) g(c)} \Bigg| = \frac{\lvert g(c) - g(x) \rvert}{ \lvert g(x) \rvert \lvert g(c) \rvert} < \varepsilon
\end{equation}
for all $x \in [a,b]$ with $\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta$.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. By continuity of $g$, there exists a $\delta_1 >0 $ such that
\begin{equation}
\lvert g(c) -g(x) \rvert < \frac{\lvert g(c) \rvert^2}{2} \varepsilon
\end{equation}
for all $x \in [a,b]$ with $\lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_1$. Moreover, since $g(c) < 0$, we find a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that 
\begin{equation}
g(x) \leq \frac{g(c)}{2} < 0
\end{equation}
for all $x \in [a,b]$ with $\lvert x- c \rvert < \delta_2$. Note that for those $x$, $\lvert g(x) \rvert \geq \frac{ \lvert g(c) \rvert}{2} $.

Let us now choose a $\delta \in \big(0, \min \{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \} \big)$. Then
\begin{equation}
\Bigg| \frac{1}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{g(c)} \Bigg| \leq \frac{2}{ \lvert g(c) \rvert^2} \lvert g(c) - g(x) \rvert < \varepsilon
\end{equation}
for all $x \in [a,b]$ with $\lvert x-c \rvert < \delta$.

Comment: Just like mine. ;-))

Answer (score 0):

A smarter proof is hinted in my comment above, but let us stick to the formulation of your exercise.

Let $m:=|g(c)|$ and fix $\epsilon>0.$ By continuity of $g,$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|g(x)-g(c)|<\eta:=\frac{\epsilon m^2}{1+\epsilon m}$$
for all $x \in [a,b]$ such that $\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta.$

For such $x$'s, we obtain: $g(x)\ne0$ (since $\eta<m$), and
$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac1{g(x)}-\frac1{g(c)}\right|&=\frac{|g(x)-g(c)|}{|g(x)||g(c)|}\\
&\le\frac\eta{(m-\eta)m}\\\\ 
&=\epsilon.
\end{align}$$

(There is no magic in the initial choice of $\eta.$ It was just found by solving the equation $\frac\eta{(m-\eta)m}=\epsilon.$)