# Can we find the limit of a function if we know the limit of its reciprocal?

Tags: limits, functions

In a question I am given that the limit of f(x) -> e as x tends to infinity
Can I assume that the limit of 1/f(x) -> 1/e as x tends to infinity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit of reciprocal function is the reciprocal of its limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537160/limit-of-reciprocal-function-is-the-reciprocal-of-its-limit)

Answer (score 1):

For sure! If a non vanishing function has a non zero limit $l$ at a point, the limit of $\frac{1}{f}$ at that point is equal to $\frac{1}{l}$.