# Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are sequences such that $X$ converges to $x\neq 0$ and $XY$ converges, then $Y$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that given convergent sequences $X$ and $XY$ then $Y$ converges.

Call arbitrarily $z_n=(x_n)(y_n)$, as by hypothesis $\lim(x_n)=x≠0$, then it must happen that $(x_n)≠0$, thus we can consider that $y_n=\frac{z_n}{x_n}$; now, assuming that $(z_n)$ tends to $z=xy$ and that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ one has that $y_n$ converges to $y$.

The above represents an attempt at a proof, but I don't know if this is the way, any help?

Comment: It's really the product of the sequences, not the sum; I guess I made a mistake typing

Comment: $(x_n)$ might be $0$, but since $x_n \to x \neq 0$, $x_n \neq 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. Then your $y_n := z_n/x_n$ is well-defined for these large $n$. Claim that $\lim y_n = z/x$. Now you could do $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to show is

$$p_n\rightarrow p,q_n\rightarrow q\neq 0\implies p_n/q_n\implies p/q$$

To show this, first show the limit of a product of sequences is the product of limits (left as an exercise):

$$a_n\rightarrow a,b_n\rightarrow b\implies a_nb_n\rightarrow ab,$$

then show the limit of a reciprocal of a sequence is the reciprocal of the limit when well-defined (proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927381/proof-limit-of-ratio-of-sequence)), and then take the case $a_n=p_n,b_n=1/q_n.$